# Android SQL compatibility

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram` and I am using `bindAllArgsAsStrings(args)` function. Currently this is compatible only for API 11 and above. Is there any alternative to this function or any library that I can use to get around this limitation.

Comment: is there any reason you are using those low level versions instead of e.g. [`SQLiteDatabase#query(String table, ...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: The accessor API wasn't written by me. I am just the guy fixing all the bugs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it programmatically:

```
for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
   bindString(i+1, args[i]);
```